# I installed Oracle JDK 14 but did not find jmc (Java Mission Control)

Tags: java, java-14

I installed Oracle JDK 14 but did not find `jmc` (Java Mission Control) in `$JAVA_HOME/bin` folder

Where is `jmc` in Oracle JDK 14?

[image: JAVA_HOME/bin]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with JDK 11, JDK Mission Control is provided as a separate download.

https://www.oracle.com/javase/jmc/

I think you can download it from

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/products-jmc7-downloads.html

Comment: updated link https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/jdk-mission-control.html